# Flutter: visual artifact above the app bar when elevation is applied to it

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having the hardest time getting rid of this faint, slight linear artifact above my AppBar when I apply elevation to it. If I remove the elevation the line goes away, however I do want to keep the elevation effect below the AppBar. I just want this darn line to go away!

You'll notice a faint grey line in between the front facing camera area and the title:

[image: Line above the app bar]

I've tried workarounds such as creating a custom preferredsizewidget, applying inner box shadows on my main container, and translating the app bar a few pixels upwards to try and hide the line. My experiments all came with their own faults, and all seem to demonstrate that line does indeed belong solely to the app bar.

Here is my main code:

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  //key to maintain the scaffold
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: navBarBG,
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
          key: _key,
          endDrawer: sideDrawer,
          body: ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: curPageIndex,
              builder: ((context, value, child) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 0, top: 5, left: 10, right: 10),
                  child: Navigator(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                      key: navigatorKey,
                      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) =>
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return 
                                pageList[curPageIndex.value];
                          }))))),
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 3,
            centerTitle: true,
            leading: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: transactionsShowing,
                builder: ((context, value, child) =>
                    (transactionsShowing.value == 1)
                        ? IconButton(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!)
                                  .maybePop({transactionsShowing.value = 0});
                              viewingTransactionID = -1;
                              viewingTransactionType = "";
                            },
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_back,
                              size: 32,
                            ))
                        : const SizedBox())),
            title: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0), child: Text("Envilo")),
            actions: [
              //Sets up the drawer button
              Transform.translate(
                  offset: const Offset(0, -12),
                  child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0),
                      child: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                          onPressed: () => {
                                (_key.currentState!.isEndDrawerOpen)
                                    ? _key.currentState!.closeEndDrawer()
                                    : _key.currentState!.openEndDrawer()
                              })))
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: const ActionButton(),
          floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
          bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(),
        )));
  }
}
```

and my appBarTheme:

```
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black, size: 38),
        elevation: 0,
        //shape: Border(top: BorderSide(width: 3, color: navBarBG)),
        toolbarHeight: 36,
        backgroundColor: navBarBG,
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            height: .8,
            letterSpacing: .6,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            fontSize: textSize + 9,
color: Colors.black)),
```

Any advice on how to keep the bottom elevation, while hiding or negating the top part of it, would be greatly appreciated. I'm already embarrassed with how many hours I've spent on this darn line that's sure to be haunting my nightmares.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After far too much trial and error I found adding a border to the app bar was enough to hide the line above it.

I used
`shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: navBarBG, width: 3)),` within the app bar and it's working exactly as I need. Thanks for looking!